# mount filesystem with kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

is there any way to mount linux filesystem (ext4,ext3 or btrfs) with linux kernel module ?
I want to write kernel module can mount filesystem , but can not use `<sys/mount.h>` inside module source code because this is user space header .
NOTE : i used customized kernel with built-in ext4,btrfs filesystem (not modularize) .

Answer (score 0):

`<sys/mount.h>` is userspace header, you can't use it for kernel module.

In-kernel API to mount filesystem is `ksys_mount()` or `do_mount()` but that is not exported to modules. If you really want to mount from kernel module (and modifying kernel is not an option for you) then you will have to duplicate ksys_mount() paths in your code.